# get scope from a certain controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I try to test my angularjs app through QUnit framework.
On the page `mysite.ru/#/unittest/` - I use a controller called `UnittestCtrl`. But in my app I have a `DetailCtrl` and other page that I want to test. The problem is that I can't get access to the scope of `DetailCtrl` from the unittest page.

That's the code that I use in order to get Unittest controller's scope on `mysite.ru/#/unittest/`. How can I get access to the scope from `DetailCtrl`?

```
var appElement = document.querySelector('[ng-app=TheApp]');
var appScope = angular.element(appElement).scope();
var controllerScope = appScope.$$childHead;
console.log(controllerScope.link);
```

I also tried this but it has no outcome:

```
var serviceLocator = angular.injector(["TheApp"])
scope = serviceLocator.get('$rootScope')
var $controller = serviceLocator.get('$controller');
$controller('DetailCtrl', {
              $scope: scope
          });
```

The error: `Unknown provider: $rootElementProvider <- $rootElement <- $location <- $route`

My DetailCtrl

```
Controllers.controller('DetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', '$route',
function($scope, $routeParams, $http, $route) {
  $scope.reloadRoute = function () {
    window.location.reload();
  };
  $scope.cityId = $routeParams.cityId;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`angular.injector` creates an injector (`ng` module is not loaded).

[`angular.bootstrap`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.7/src/Angular.js#L1651-L1692) calls `angular.injector` to create the injector (`ng` module is loaded) and attaches it to some DOM element. It creates `$rootElement` service.

To match `angular.bootstrap` functionality in tests, `$rootElement` should be mocked:

```
angular.injector([
  'ng',
  ($provide) => {
    $provide.value('$rootElement', angular.element('<div>'))
  },
  'app'
]);
```

Or better, use `angular-mock` that does this and much more.

```
angular.injector(['ngMock', 'app']);
```

It binds itself to Jasmine and Mocha and loads `ngMock` automatically, but it is not an option for QUnit.

But the actual problem that should be addresses here is router. In unit tests the unit should be isolated from other units, other units (`$route` and `$routeParams` service) should be mocked. It can be done in injector or in `$controller`, which allows to override the dependencies from injector:

```
var mockedRoute = { ... }.
var mockedRouteParams = { ... };

$controller('DetailCtrl', {
  $scope: scope,
  $route: mockedRoute,
  $routeParams: mockedRouteParams 
});
```